# How to generate tab-delimited txt file?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, csv

I want to use SQL SERVER 2005 commands to generate tab-delimited file.  I want to create a complex query and give it to something (say a function) to export data with columns names into a tab-delimited file.

If u don't know something doing this, suggest an idea that reduces the headache of doing it from scratch using C#.

AHH, I am not willing to learn SSRS as I'm supposed to finish this in one day, but if this is the only way, tell me.

Thank u for ur time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try out SQL Server **bcp.exe** tool

Comment: I did not try that programaticaly but from msdn it should work.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear from your question whether you just need to achieve the tab-delimited output, or whether you need to do it programmatically. If this is just for a one-off task, then I suggest you use SQL Server Management Studio.

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Text` and set the output format to "Tab delimited". Ok that change, then run your query using SSMS, making sure you have "Results to Text" enabled (`Query -> Results To -> Results to Text`). You will need to use a new query window as only new query windows pick up the settings changes.

The output of your query should now show in the results window with tab delimiters.

*Obviously, this is not much help if you need to achieve this programmatically.*

Comment: Great tip about using a new query window. I was scratching my head why the settings changes were not taking effect!